# Python - List of Strings to Java

Tags: java, python

I'm getting a list of strings from python code and need to read it in Java. When trying to read it, i get the hashCode

> `[Ljava.lang.Object;@7cf1bb78`

I want to read the values in a list. In python my return is something like

```
return SUCCESS(OK, params={'data':nameList()})
```

How would I read this in Java and print the contents not the hashCode. Currently I'm doing like

```
Object getNames = new Object();
getName = getNameList(); // This is thru Apache XML RPC Client
System.out.println(getName);
```

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Uhm... your code is a bit confusing as you initialize the Object getNames, then "overwrite" it with an hashmap, then use another different object altogether, "getName" (without the "s"); if you want to print the list you have to iterate through it

Comment: getNames was a typo, I've corrected it. The reason for overwriting the Object with Hashmap was since I was trying to make it generic, anyway that doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have what you want. Try `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(getName));` (the default `toString()` for an array in Java is not very useful).

Comment: I tried System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString((Object[]) getAccount)); and the output was []

Any other was to try it?

Comment: This means you got an empty array back. Make sure that the server sends something useful.

Comment: There was some code issue in Python also, anyway thanks for the solution, it works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to print out each item in a Java array would be something like:

```
for (Object name: (Object[]) getNameList()) {
  System.out.println(name);
}
```

But I suspect from your response to Aaron Digulla that (as he says) you're getting an empty array back. Try printing it out on the Python side and see if there's anything in it.